# How to extend existing javascript type without type checking errors in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When using vscode, with type checking turned on in `jsconfig.json`, is it possible to extend built-in types such as `Date` and have the type checker accept it?

For example, with the following code:

```
/** @return {number}  time now in seconds */
Date.nowInSeconds = function nowInSeconds() {
    return Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
};
console.log(Date.nowInSeconds());
```

I get the following type errors:

[image: adding a static method to Date]

and similarly if you try and define a member function:

[image: adding a member method to Date]

Comment: Do `Date` and `DateConstructor` are same object? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: check that `nowInSeconds` exists in the `Date` type

Comment: @Jai `DateConstructor` is what vscode's typescript engine calls the [standard `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You should call the prototype, Date.prototype.someFunction = function blah() {}

Comment: @squeekyDave that would add a member function, I'm adding a static method similar to `Date.now()`

Comment: @squeekyDave https://jsfiddle.net/zgbso8kh/1/ it does work. You aren't answering the question; I'm not asking about a runtime errors, I'm asking about a type checking error in vscode.

Comment: @squeekyDave almost everything you said is incorrect. Please don't parrot nonsense unless you're prepared to back it up with references to the language spec. Constructors are Function objects (**not** prototype objects) and just like any Function objects can have any property (including *function* properties, i.e. methods) added to them at any point, and these are a perfectly good analog of static class methods.

Comment: @m0tive I doubt it's going to work: from a typing standpoint to modify an existing type you make a new one that inherits from (or shares an interface implementation with) an older one. It doesn't really make sense for a static type system to let you modify the contract of a type at runtime.

Comment: @JaredSmith I suspected that was the case, but I wondered if there was some magic to tell the type system that it was extended within my project (like in a type def file, or something?)

Comment: @m0tive I imagine you could possibly hack your way around it by defining the method with `Object.defineProperty` and then invoking the method indirectly, but then you might lose the type system's ability to warn you of errors. It all rather begs the question why you don't just create a simple standalone function rather than investing so much effort in defeating the type system. If you really want to go down that route, I'd look at some polyfill libraries that conditionally add eg. `Array.from` and see how they do it.

Comment: The advantage I see is that type-specific methods (e.g. methods on `String`) are accessible directly on that type (e.g. `"my string".foobar()`) without having to have a utils module passed around the application. I'll have a look at polyfil and see how they do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define method on 3rd party class using typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565706/how-to-define-method-on-3rd-party-class-using-typescript)

Comment: @m0tive apparently it is indeed possible. Not sure if that's a good or bad thing.