# How to define method on 3rd party class using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extend a 3rd party class but am having trouble getting typescript to play nice. Basically, I can't use any existing method already defined in the class in my new method.

A workaround would be to redefine existing methods in `extensions.ts` (see below), but there just has to be a better way.

#### 3rd party `index.d.ts`

```
export as namespace thirdParty;

export Class SomeClass {
  // some methods here
}
```

#### My `extensions.ts`

```
import {thirdParty} from 'thirdParty'

declare module 'thirdParty' {
    namespace thirdParty {
        class SomeClass{
            newMethod(): this

            // works if I redfine the method here
            originalExistingMethod(): number
        }
    }
}

thirdParty.SomeClass.prototype.newMethod = function() {
    return this.originalExistingMethod() + 1
}
```

When calling an existing method like `this.originalExistingMethod()` above, typescript complains:

`TS2339: Property 'originalExistingMethod' does not exist on type 'SomeClass'`

Is there a way to avoid having to redefine existing methods when performing [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)?

Comment: The real question is: why are you trying to modify third party class? This is a bad practice to say mildly. Because it's a bad practice you will have hard time to find good/correct solution for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Initial Answer

Here is [an example](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-module-augmentation-class-prototype) using the Tensorflow library.

extend.ts

```
import { AdadeltaOptimizer } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';

declare module '@tensorflow/tfjs-core' {
    interface AdadeltaOptimizer {
        newMethod(message: string): void;
    }
}

AdadeltaOptimizer.prototype.newMethod = function (message: string) {
    console.log('===============');
    console.log(message);
    console.log('===============');
}
```

index.ts

```
import { AdadeltaOptimizer } from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import "./extend";

const optimizer = new AdadeltaOptimizer(10, 10);

// the existing method is present
const className = optimizer.getClassName();

// the augmentation is also present
optimizer.newMethod(`The className is ${className}.`);
```

There is a similar example [in the official TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), which augments `Observable` with a `map` method.

#### Follow Up on Comments

> Thanks. Though my issue is using existing methods when defining newMethod. So in extend.ts not in index.ts. Any ideas on this?

This also works in `extend.ts` as follows:

```
import { AdadeltaOptimizer } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';

declare module '@tensorflow/tfjs-core' {
    interface AdadeltaOptimizer {
        newMethod(message: string): void;
    }
}

AdadeltaOptimizer.prototype.newMethod = function (message: string) {

    // just access the original method on `this` 
    const className = this.getClassName();

    console.log('===============');
    console.log(className);
    console.log(message);
    console.log('===============');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though my issue is using existing methods when defining `newMethod`. So in `extend.ts` not in `index.ts`. Any ideas on this?

Comment: That will work in the same way. I'll post an update.

Comment: Thanks for the example repo Shaun! I cloned it and it still wasn't working BUT.... turns out there was something in yarn's cache that was the real culprit! Verified by installing the modules with `npm install`. To fix yarn's issue, I ran `yarn cache clean && yarn install` and no more ts errors!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that worked out in the end. Nice catch on the yarn cache.