# Typescript extending third party class error: ElementHandle only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript, interface, extension-methods, puppeteer

I am trying to extend [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)'s class ElementHandle with one method. I have checked some examples and wrote simple code just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53566553/5235756).

But VSCode shows me an error for the line where I change ElementHandle prototype:

> 'ElementHandle' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here.ts(2693)

How can I fix it?

My code:

```
import { ElementHandle } from 'puppeteer';

declare module 'puppeteer' {
    interface ElementHandle {
        scrollIntoView(): void;
    }
}

ElementHandle.prototype.scrollIntoView = async function (): Promise<void> {
    await this._scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
}
```

ElementHandle class:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/src/JSHandle.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is accurate: in the case of Puppeter, the `ElementHandle` refers to a *type*, not to a class / object / value.

In Typescript, types exist only at compile-time. Then, at run-time, they don't exist at all, they are completely removed.

For this reason, the statement:

```js
ElementHandle.prototype.scrollIntoView = async function() { /* */ }
```

Won't work. Since ElementHandle is a only *type*, it won't exist on runtime, so you can't send the `.prototype` message in an attempt to access to it.

An interpretation here would be that `ElementHandle` is just an abstract *representation* of some entities handled by puppeteer,  not a reference that has entity and/or can be used as a template, like a class.

Therefore, it's just not possible to assign a function (or any value, for that matter) to it "extend" it like you want to do.